# "Find substring in char[]" getting unexpected results

Tags: java, arrays, methods, char

Disclaimer: This is a bit of a homework question. I'm attempting to write a `contains(java.lang.String subString)` method , that returns an `int` value representing the index of the comparison string within the primary string, for a custom-made String class.

Some of the rules:

- No collection classes
- Only charAt() and toCharArray() are allowed from the java String class (but methods from other classes are allowed)
- Assume `length()` returns the length of the primary string (which is exactly what it does)

My Code:

```
public int contains(java.lang.String subString) {
    this.subString = subString;
    char[] arrSubStr = this.subString.toCharArray();
    //Create initial fail
    int index = -1;
    //Make sure comparison subString is the same length or shorter than the primary string
    if(arrSubStr.length > length()) {
        return index;
    }
    //Steps to perform if initial conditions are met
    else {
        //Compare first character of subString to each character in primary string
        for(int i = 0; i < length(); i++) {
            //When a match is found...
            if(arrSubStr[0] == this.content[i]) {
                //...make sure that the subString is not longer than the remaining length of the primary string
                if(arrSubStr.length > length() - i) {
                    return index;
                }
                //Proceed matching remainder of subString
                else {
                    //Record the index of the beginning of the subString contained in primary string
                    index = i;
                    //Starting with second character of subString...
                    for(int j = 1; j < arrSubStr.length;) {
                        //...compare with subsequent chars of primary string, 
                        //and if a failure of match is found, reset index to failure (-1)
                        if(arrSubStr[j] != this.content[j+i]) {
                            index = -1;
                            return index;
                        }
                        //If we get here, it means whole subString match found
                        //Return the index (=i) we set earlier
                        else {
                            return index;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
return index;
}
```

Results from testing:

Primary string: `asdfg`
Comparison string: `donkey`
Result: `-1` [PASS]

Primary string: `asdfg`
Comparison string: `asdfg`
Result: `0` [PASS]

Primary string: `asdfg`
Comparison string: `g`
Result: `4` [PASS]

Primary string: `asasasf`
Comparison string: `asd`
Result: `0` [**FAIL**] (should be `-1`)

Primary string: `asasasf`
Comparison string: `asf`
Result: `0` [**FAIL**] (should be `4`)

The comments reflect how the code is intended to work. However its clear that when it reaches the second `for` loop, the logic is breaking down somehow to give the results above. But I can't see the problem. Could I get a second set of eyes on this?

Comment: You inner for-loop only can ever iterate one time, since both branches of the if-statement therein return index.  I think you meant to check whether the for-loop terminated without a match, but you're always returning -1 or 1 depending on if the first character matches.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Is the solution to replace one of the return statements with a `continue`?

Comment: I think you can just move the second `return index` outside of the for-loop.  You'll only reach that if the check inside the loop didn't return a -1.  Not at a computer with an IDE, so I can't actually try it... ;-)

Comment: Side comment: I think this is one of the best questions I have seen asking for help on assignment. This shows a fair degree of research, trial-and-error and understanding. Also tell us right in the face it's for assignment.

Comment: First of all, for certain-fail conditions, just return a constant `-1` (you can declare a `final` int at the start of the method). For inner loops, you should use `break` to jump out of the inner loop when a fail-condition is met, this will cause the outer loop to continue.

Comment: Annnddd BOOM. Solved. I'll post the solution. Thanks azurefrog and Jai, you were both massively helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
//If we get here, it means whole subString match found
//Return the index (=i) we set earlier
else {
    return index;
}
```

This assumption is not correct unfortunately. If you get there, it means that the second character of both substrings are identical since the `if-else` statement will only get executed once and both ends contains a `return`.

The way to solve this is probably easy now that I've diagnosed the problem but I want to go a bit further with this. The way we try to write code on a daily basis is a way in which the code we use can be maintainable, reusable and *testable*.

This means basically that the function we have here could be easily sliced up in different little functions invoked one after the other for which we could write unit tests and receive a quick feedback on whether a set of logical statements fit or not.

Comment: Thanks Yassin. I was able to solve this specific problem using comments from others, but your advice is well-valued and will help with my further coding efforts.

Comment: @Soundscape Pleased I could help. Good luck further and very good job writing such clean code and question ;). Keep up

Answer (score 1):

With suggestions from Jai and azurefrog in the comments, I was able to solve the issues by re-writing the logic to the following (somewhat abridged):

```
    if(arrSubStr.length > length()) {
        return index;
    }
    //Steps to perform if initial conditions are met
    else {
        //Compare first character of subString to each character in primary string
        for(int i = 0; i < length(); i++) {
            //When a match is found...
            if(arrSubStr[0] == this.content[i]) {
                //...make sure that the subString is not longer than the remaining length of the primary string
                if(arrSubStr.length <= length() - i) {
                    //Record the index of the beginning of the subString contained in primary string
                    index = i;
                    //Starting with second character of subString...
                    for(int j = 1; j < arrSubStr.length; j++) {
                        //...compare with subsequent chars of primary string, 
                        //and if a failure of match is found, reset index to failure (-1)
                        if(arrSubStr[j] != this.content[j+i]) {
                            index = -1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
return index;
```

Essentially, I removed all of the `return` statements from within the loops. Simply setting the `index` value appropriately and making use of the final (outside) `return` statement was, in hindsight, the correct way to approach the problem. I then also added a `break;` to the inner `for` loop to make sure that a failure to match would continue the loop ticking through. I'm sure there's still unnecessary code in there, but while its still passing the requisite tests, I'm encouraged to leave it the hell alone. :)
I'm still a novice at Java, so I hope this explanation made sense.

Comment: You need to return `index` when you are comparing the last `char` of the substring (it has to be a match as well). Your current implementation probably fails when doing `"hello".contains("ll")`. (I didn't run it to test though)